# Foot bone rotates when IK bone is moved up or down

Tags: rigging, bones, bone.constraints

The foot bone, instead of staying flat when I move the IK bone up or down, rotates. I tried adding a copy rotate constraint to the IK mover bone that doesn't rotate but the foot bone still rotates.

Here is a link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7xcXlophIFLhbRQHUgmO6LDq9KeK0WW/view?usp=share_link

[image: Footbone rotates]

[image: Footbone flat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foot rotates because it's child of the shin bone.
One way to solve is to delete the copy rot constraint, go to edit mode, select the foot bone, shift select the IK controller bone, press Ctrl P > set parent (keep offset), so that the rot of the foot will be determined by the rotation of the IK controller.

Comment: Heck YASSS thanks you :') XOXOX